# PHP regular expression search for includes, then write the includes where it found them

Tags: php, regex, templates, include

I have [this script](http://pastebin.com/7wF3MCQP) (well commented!) that searches files in a folder using regular expressions, removes comments and HTML, but leaves the tag intact. I would want this script to do the same, but instead of leaving tag's intact, it need to print the include it finds to file.

For example:

```
<!--TPFILE--><?include '/module/menu.html';?><!--TPFILEEND-->
```

So the goal is to print out the HTML from menu.html to where the regular expression found the include.
I'm very new to PHP but understand the basics, though, I'm stuck on this one.

EDIT: I found a solution, it's posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use

> preg_replace_callback

And create a new function and use file_get_contents:

```
function repl_str($matches)
{
  // $matches[1] the match for the first subpattern
  return file_get_contents($matches[1]);
}
```

Here is a link to the :
[completed script snippet](http://pastebin.com/yY2RD6YB)

Answer (score 1):

Is this syntax required : `<?include '/module/menu.html';?>`?   Could you replace this with `<?php include '/blah/foo.php';?>`?  If so, you could either directly include the file, or use `token_get_all()` to split the HTML up in to PHP chunks and normal string (HTML) output.

Comment: Sorry if im being daft, but could you show me an example of what you mean by this, i have tried reading up on token_get_all() but i still don't follow what your getting at. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Here you go:  https://gist.github.com/1008378   Just an idea really, `token_get_all()` splits the input as if it were being processed by the PHP engine, so it does all the hard work of extracting the "executable" bits of the HTML string for you.  If you're not able to change the `<?include .. ?>` syntax then this is no use to you.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but i solved it by using preg_replace_callback and file_get_contents in a new function.